# Strength of steel tube

Tags: safety

What is the minimum size rectangle steel tube needed to lift 500 lbs with the fulcrum in the middle of a seven foot tube?  Assume a minimum of 1.5 inches outside dimensions, long side vertical.    E.g:  2.5X 1.5.

---

Response to clarification:

The fulcrum will be a 1/2" diameter eye bolt.

I am assuming the tube to be mild steel.  E.g:  1010, 1020, etc.

Not for repetitive use.  Once a week at the most.

Comment: do you want to do this repetitively?  i.e. how much do you care about metal fatigue?

Comment: What is this for?

Comment: Well, that surely can be computed. I'm afraid, though, that You may need an answer according to some country's code. Or You want it to over-compute it for like 200% of design resistance? Also, depending on what You got in shops, it may be nice to have steel designation and exact dimension numbers.

Answer (score 1):

That will depend on exact details of the tube's thickness and alloy, how force is being applied at the fulcrum, ... I suggest getting expert advice on this one and buying something spec'd by forces it has to carry rather than trying to guess by size.

Comment: How that fulcrum is designed is highly important, you don't want the tube folding because the wall got crimped.